# С помощью функции root.withdraw() можно скрыть окно в Tkinter, но как его вернуть обратно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

С помощью функции root.withdraw() можно скрыть окно в Tkinter, но как его вернуть обратно? Гуглил, но ничего не нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если хотите вернуть

```
root.deiconify()
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!)

Comment: @Роман Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour